# How to find common elements only between 2 arrays in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

I have two arrays like above. Now I want to do the following in MVC 4 with jQuery.

1. If every elements of both arrays are equal then show a message/alert. e.g. "All records already existing."
2. If every elements of both the arrays are different then just add them all in a "VAR", e.g. `var resultset = ....` (where 7,8,9 will stored)
3. If few elements common between two arrays then for the common elements show a message with element, e.g. "Record 1,2,3,4,5,6 are already exists" and add the different elements in "VAR", e.g. `var resultset = ....` (where 7,8,9 will stored). Both the message and difference elements collection will perform at the same time.

Comment: Is the element in two array always sorted ?

Comment: Yes, by some other process these arrays are creating and it will never be empty... Thanks !!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Try this:

```
    var array1  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var common = $.grep(array1, function(element) {
    return $.inArray(element, array2 ) !== -1;
});

console.log(common); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];



var array3 = array2.filter(function(obj) { return array1.indexOf(obj) == -1; });

// returns [7,8,9];
```

Comment: I think in $.grep(a, function(element) here "a" will be replaced by "array1"

Comment: Coomon part is working fine...but the rest  i.e. the difference is not working

Comment: i edited that part also please check . i put array1 instaead of array2 now

Comment: Look at this array3 now

Comment: Thanks Tamizh, Its working fine...Thanks a lot friend

Comment: Can you please tell me here how I can add this array3 value to a normal var but in a comma seperated way...

Comment: I can't do that...need your help...waiting man..

Comment: `array1 = [2, 2, 2, 5]` and `array2 = [2, 2, 5, 5]` should result in `[2, 2, 5]` but with the code above we get `[2, 2, 2, 5]`. https://jsfiddle.net/mpaatc2n/1/

Answer (score 6):

Here is my [version](http://jsfiddle.net/hrLHR/3/)

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
        var obj = {}, matched = [],
            unmatched = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = arr1.length; i < l; i++) {
            obj[arr1[i]] = (obj[arr1[i]] || 0) + 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            var val = arr2[i];
            if (val in obj) {
                matched.push(val);
            } else {
                unmatched.push(val);
            }
        }
        // Here you can find how many times an element is repeating.
        console.log(obj);
        // Here you can find what are matching.
        console.log(matched);
        // Here you can check whether they are equal or not.
        console.log('Both are equal ? :' + 
        matched.length === a.length);
        // Here you can find what are different  
        console.log(unmatched);
    }
```

Comment: Lovely. This is the only function I could find that gives me a matched `[2]` when comparing `[2, 2, 2]` with `[2, 5, 5]`. Thanks.

Comment: PS: Does not work for `diff([2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 5, 5])` which will result in matches `[2, 2, 5, 5]` instead of expected `[2, 2, 5]`. http://jsfiddle.net/hrLHR/14/

Answer (score 5):

If you do this kind of thing regularly, you may be interested in a Set object that makes this kind of stuff pretty easy:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var common = new Set(array1).intersection(array2).keys();
```

The open source Set object (one simple source file) is here: https://github.com/jfriend00/Javascript-Set/blob/master/set.js

Along with the `intersection()` method used here, it has all sorts of other set operations (union, difference, subset, superset, add, remove ...).

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5SCdD/