# How to code a non brutal search

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm coding a javascript snippet that searches for a match between two arrays. I know how to search it brutally (array takes a number input, searches each value of the other arrays to see if they match do this over and over again) but it is very inefficient. If anyone knows a way to search for a common value between two arrays so that it takes minimum time possible, please help me.

```
var 1 = ["bob", "Sophie"];
var 2 = ["Sherry", "Gerard", "Joseph"];

for(var i; i <= 1.length; i++){

switch(1[i]){

case 1[i] === 2[1]:
console.log("They match!");

break;

case 1[i] === 2[2]:
console.log("They match!");

break;

case 1[i] === 2[3]:
console.log("They match!");

break;

case default:
console.log("No matches found.");

}
}
}
```

PS Don mind the syntax errors, this is a "Rough draft" of the code. I put it just so that you could see what I meant.

Comment: Post an example with what you've tried.

Comment: How large will the arrays be? Instinctively I'd say it would be fastest (for larger arrays) to sort the array and then search it.

Comment: @IvanModric the arrays will be pretty big, around 200 values will be stored in them on average. How can I sort arrays?

Comment: You could google 'quicksort'. This seems to be an ok implementation, but I'm on a mobile phone at the moment so I can't properly edit the comment or check the code: https://gist.github.com/paullewis/1981455

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table and iterate the first array to create a table and then just filter the second array with a single loop.

[Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): O(n + m)

```js
var array1 = ["bob", "Sophie"],
    array2 = ["Sherry", "Gerard", "Joseph"],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    found;

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a] = true;
});

found = array2.filter(function (a) {
    return hash[a];
});
console.log(found);

array2.push("Sophie");
found = array2.filter(function (a) {
    return hash[a];
});
console.log(found);
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var array1 = ["bob", "Sophie"],
    array2 = ["Sherry", "Gerard", "Joseph"],
    aSet = new Set(array1),
    found;

found = array2.filter(a => aSet.has(a));
console.log(found);

array2.push("Sophie");
found = array2.filter(a => aSet.has(a));
console.log(found);
```

Comment: ... assuming that the hash lookups/inserts are O(1). In theory, they will rather by O(log(n))

Comment: actually the building of the table is O(n) plus the lookup for the value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to find common elements. Then I will go with Underscore.Js external library (as given in below snippet) or there are other solutions suggested in the following link
[How to find common elements only between 2 arrays in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163143/how-to-find-common-elements-only-between-2-arrays-in-jquery)

```js
var array1 = ["bob", "Sophie"];
var array2 = ["bob", "Gerard", "Joseph"];

alert(_.intersection(array1, array2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```